# Get shade of blue based of a number

Tags: javascript, math, colors

I have an Object like following:

```
{
  "id1": 0,
  "id2": 10,
  "id3": 51,
  "id4": 2
}
```

The Object has over 200 items. Each value is a random number, >=0.

- maxValue; the biggest number in of the Object values.
- minValue; 0

All of these values are part of a large html grid, each one having a number in its innerHTML like following:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/946057540687515658/1163523785962553404/Screenshot_20231016_190204_Sheets.jpg?ex=653fe2f7&is=652d6df7&hm=02857d9a3b6621f1c4328ef2f41fc4558de14d642c681c42b14af26d5aac989a&

Each grid cell should be given a color, a shade of blue, according to how large the number is. maxValue, the biggest value, should have the darkest blue (3, 82, 255) and values close to the minValue should be more white / lightblue.

Like the following example:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/946057540687515658/1163524382904287374/Screenshot_20231016_190121_Sheets.jpg?ex=653fe386&is=652d6e86&hm=5c1519dfb9a31555e10158771bf683921ba8c1da8cd668f620df91dfa8fc79b6&

How can I achieve something like this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look into HSV/HSL color coding, Blue tint can be controlled via their components.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the new color by separating the red/gree/blue parts and take the integer parts

```js
class RGB {
    constructor (r, g, b) {
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

const
    getNormalized = (min, max, left, right) => v => (v - min) * (right - left) / (max - min) + left,
    prepareColor = (rgbA, rgbB, min, max) => value => [
        getNormalized(min, max, rgbA.r, rgbB.r)(value),
        getNormalized(min, max, rgbA.g, rgbB.g)(value),
        getNormalized(min, max, rgbA.b, rgbB.b)(value)
    ].map(v => Math.floor(v).toString(16).padStart(2, 0)).join(''),
    getColor = prepareColor(new RGB(255, 255, 255), new RGB(3, 82, 255), 1, 84);

console.log(getColor(1));
console.log(getColor(41.5));
console.log(getColor(84));
```